# Undefined function or variable in compiled matlab file

Tags: matlab, mcc

I'm trying to execute a compiled matlab script. When I run the same script in the matlab command window, it works fine, nevertheless, when I try to run the compiled version, I get this error message: "Undefined function or variable". When i was debugging the code, I found what could possible be the error. That missing variable was declared in another ".m" script file. Is this a problem  from the compiler command? I've tried to include the variable declaration file within the compiler command, but the problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

You should declare your variable as global in original *.m script:

```
global var
var= 100;
```

You can find more [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Global-Variables.html)